# How to deploy node /express /sequelize backend with lambda and RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have built and deployed a react front end on AWS amplify. I don't want to use amplify for the back end. What I want to do is deploy a node back end with express and sequelize and interact with a postgres database with a lamda server running the node code.

I can't seem to find a decent tutorial for this. A lot of stuff pushes you to use Amplify and quite frankly, it is terrible.

I've looked at a few blog articles that use serverless and don't talk about hooking up to a database - just deploying the back end and using it to respond to a request.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hooking up to a database would be like any other code. Basically, you just need to ensure that your lambda has the credentials to log into the database. There are a few ways to skin this cat though. For instance, you could:

- Pass the database information (host, creds, etc) as environment vars to the lambda.
- Add your credentials to Secrets Manager, and add code to your lambda to pull the secrets
- A combination of the above.

This article provides a good starting point for this as a proof of concept:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-securely-provide-database-credentials-to-lambda-functions-by-using-aws-secrets-manager/

Basically, it leverages secrets manager for the creds, and you pass the ARN of the secret to the lambda. This is likely the most secure option.

Now, to interact with this lambda from your frontend, you will want to leverage API Gateway. However, another option would be to use a newer feature: function urls:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints/

I am not sure of your use case exactly. If you are just experimenting, maybe lambda function urls are enough. If you are looking to do something that's a bit more...beefy... just go API Gateway; you'll have more options for extensibility.

Comment: But, how do I go about deploying the node back end to the lambda and setting it up so that it queries the database through the api gateway?

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood a bit. you wouldn't need the api gateway to query your database. you would query your database like you would with any other back-end node application. I am not really a node.js guy, so I dont know the specifics of this. I suggest you start by creating a lambda manually using the node runtime provided by AWS. then try to add code in there to make a sample DB call. once you have that figured out, you can piece it together.

Comment: It would really help if there was an AWS or other explanation of how to handle this. This seems like the primary use case for lambda, RDS, and gateways. The fact that there isn't a plain example makes me think that I am looking at this all wrong

Comment: I think you might be overcomplicating it in your head. Break this down into smaller pieces. First, go through that first link I shared. Get the basics down for connecting to a database from a lambda. Then, you can figure out how to glue your frontend to tour backend with api gateway. I know its a LOT to absorb, but if you break it down by service, then you just glue it all together.

Comment: I went through the links and I've seen them before. I am simply trying to deploy a node express app to a lambda and connect to it through a api gateway. I am not interested in the cloud formation aspect of it or in the specifics of storing the secrets. Those are related items, but not the question I am asking and not things that should be needed to do the core work.